# Get longest of two string s

Tags: java, string

Is there a quick way to select the longer of two strings? I want to circumvent having to do

```
if(string1 > string2)
  do a;
else if(string2 > string1)
  do b;
```

Comment: You say "longer" but your example shows "greater".

Comment: Remember also this: string longer = string1.Length > string2.Length ? string1 : string2;

Comment: What happens if they are the same length?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String have a method [`length`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) you can use:

```
if(string1.length() > string2.length())
  do a;
else if(string2.length() > string1.length()
  do b;
```

---

**Edit:** I misunderstood your question. This would be a shorter way to write it using a *ternary operator*:

```
String longest = (string1.length() > string2.length()) ? string1 : string2;
```

---

I don't know why you are looking for a shorter way to write it since your original way gives much more readability than using a ternary operator. If the reason is that you're going to get the longest string many times I'd recommend to extract the comparison to a method that returns the longest string instead. E.g:

```
public String getLongestString(String s1, String s2) {
   if(s1.length() > s2.length())
      return s1;
   else
      return s2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, putting it in a method is indeed the easier way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If your doA() or doB() return values of the same super type, you could always use the ternary:

```
final Object result = string1.length() > string2.length() ? doA() : doB();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you care about whether it's a tie, you do need to do both comparisons.

If you don't care if it's a tie, you can drop the second comparison. A tie will then be the same as the second string being longer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `if(string1 > string2)` you should be doing like

```
if(length(string1) >= length(string2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going to work with the longer string, this might do the trick:

```
String s1 = "a";
String s2 = "bb";
String longer;
longer = s1.length() > s2.length()? s1: s2.length() > s1.length()? s2:null;
if (longer != null) System.out.println("longer string: " + longer);
```

But I would prefer to use the two ifs for readability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string1.length() > string2.length()) {
  //do a
}
else {
  //do b
}
```

Comment: What if they're the same size?

Answer (score 0):

I believe no, but you could simplify it a bit:

```
if (s1.length() >= s2.length()) {
    // do a
} else {
    // do b
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing that the OP's code does. You're arbitrarily combining equality with greater than.

Comment: @Polynomial, I think you misunderstood the question, the OP is asking about the "longer of two strings", in Java you use `length()` to determine the length, not direct comparison; in fact `string1 > string2` produces an error. Reconsider your downvote

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of the `length()` method. What I'm saying is that if `string1.length()` is equal to `string2.length()` your code will execute the first branch. In OP's code, if `string1.length()` is equal to `string2.length()` nothing will happen. Your logic is incorrect, and you're arbitrarily dumping that equality case in with your greater than case.

Comment: Yes, it would execute the first branch and it would be valid possibility, since something has got to be done in the case of length equality, and the pseudocode of the OP omits that case, it's up to the OP to decide if that's wrong, not you

Comment: OP stated a set of requirements, which your code does not follow. You can't invent functionality just because you think it should be there, let alone do so with no explanation of your reasoning. You don't know what the context is, so it could be completely wrong. It's bad practice to implement behaviour when behaviour is undefined in the specification. In fact, it's up the the OP to decide how they want to handle equality, not you.

Answer (score 0):

Others already pointed out to ternary if, so here another solutions.

Note, that I'm not advocating it, as the readability may be worse than your original code. I'm just listing different option.

You can try something along the following lines:

```
// Math.signum works on doubles or floats, and returns double or float,
// so we need to cast it to int, because switch wants it 
int diff = (int) Math.signum(string1.length() - string2.length()); 

switch (diff) {
    case  1: do_A(); break;
    case -1: do_B(); break;
    default: break; // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code isn't valid. You can't equate `>` or `<` directly to strings.

```
if(string1.length() > string2.length())
{
    // string1 is longer
}
else if(string2.length() > string1.length())
{
    // string2 is longer
}
```

Anyway, you can't really write this any shorter, nor should you for readability purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I know I should do length but it seems there is no way to circumvent the use of two if-statements.

Comment: You shouldn't try to circumvent them. The structure is there to preserve readability. Trying to mangle this down into a one-liner just obfuscates the logic and flow.

Comment: And what about the case when the strings are of equal length?

Comment: @Polynomial, since there is only 2 string; do you really need the else condition ... I don't think so. what say?

Comment: @Rahul - Yes, you need the else condition. It could be equal.

Comment: @Oscar - OP's code doesn't do anything when they're equal. Neither does mine. It's also rather silly to downvote someone's valid answer just because they downvoted you.

Comment: @Rahul, Óscar López, the question says "select the longer of two". Equal isn't longer.

Comment: Im indeed only interested in the longest of the two, not equality. I'm pretty sure now there's now way around it, except for the ternary operator solution